# Need help identifying a substance

Tags: adhesive

A couple years ago I bought a universal windshield mount that will hold a cell phone or GPS that used a suction cup to stick to the windshield. On the suction cup was a clear gel substance that has the consistency of hair mousse, thick and tacky. As it never dries out, the suction cup only rarely looses the seal. Compared to similar devices I have used I would estimate this goo keeps a seal several times longer then an untreated suction cup; it is a great suction cup hack.

What is this stuff, the goo? What is it called, and are there brand names for it?

Comment: that's all I got

Comment: Would grease work? Silicone grease tends to not interact with rubbers, while petroleum grease may damage some rubbers and plastics.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the Universal Cel Phone Mount is a **[Grip Go Mobile Phone Holder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnOH1nrt8MY)**.

A simple web search for "suction cup sticky gel seal" brought up the review information on YouTube. Please forgive me for NOT providing the direct link for such a product search question.

Comment: Note that using ammonia, bleach, alcohol, or any other cleaning material than plain fresh water will irreparably damage the stick surface.

Comment: The specific product is not a cell phone mount. It is the sticky substance. Sorry no upvote. (speaking of tacky things, don't ask for upvotes, move us with a good expert answer and upvotes you will recieve)

Comment: Stan I am not talking about a mount, I am talking about a gooey substance to enhance the seal of a suction cup, the mount is just background to the use. The mount was just some no brand thing bought at a truck stop.

Comment: No Stan it was not that mount. Stan, why are you trying to answer a question you do not understand, nor have an answer for? I did due diligence searching online before posting a question here. Its the goo I am looking for, hopefully in a tube. I am not asking for research, I am looking for someone with expert knowledge because they understand what the stuff is and can tell me about it. Thanks for your try but it is not a good answer.

Comment: @Jon That's an easy question. I'm looking for the same stuff; but, I can't get anything (your so-called due diligence) from you to help me in a team effort. You're right, though, I'll keep looking and leave you to your fate. I did find what I wanted applied to another type of gadget (not a phone mount); but, like you I couldn't find the supplier of the—very light blue—sticky stuff. Good luck and good bye.